# Show Div Onclick of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple buttons, each showing a subject name.
Example: English, Maths, Social, French etc..

On Click of any of these buttons, it's content should be shown.
the content is unique for each button(subject). 
I have only one div container.
when a particular button is selected, the corresponding content is shown, and when next button is showed, the current content should be replaced by new button content, and all these should happen on Click only.

Am very new to java script and query, please try to help me.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="graybox">
    <button type="button">English</button>
    <button type="button">Math</button>
    <button type="button">French</button>
    <button type="button">Social</button>
</div>

<div id="whitebox">
    on click of the subject above, respective content will be shown here, 
</div>
```

PS:The subjects will come from Database, it can be 5 subjects or 8 or any number. so subject name and number are not fixed.

Comment: create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: `_content of english/math/french/social_` How is it maintained?

Comment: i think you miss the content of subject in your HTML . Please post that also ..

Answer (score 0):

Make a CSS-class with display:none and apply it to the divs, then remove the class from the divs on button click via Javascript.
Post HTML if you need more detailled help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><button>English</button> <span>English Description</span></li>
         <li><button>Maths</button> <span>Maths Description</span></li>
         <li><button>Social</button> <span>Social Description</span></li>
         <li><button>French</button> <span>French Description</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings("span").show();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/we296/)**

Comment: i can't use it, because i have only one container, once i click maths button, English content should be replaced by maths content, on same container.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><button>English</button> <span>English Description</span></li>
         <li><button>Maths</button> <span>Maths Description</span></li>
         <li><button>Social</button> <span>Social Description</span></li>
         <li><button>French</button> <span>French Description</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="subtext">
</div>
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/we296/9/)

```
$("button").click(function() {
 $('#subtext').html($(this).next().html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try finding the text and i guess you have same id of divs which corresponds with button text like

`<button type="button">English</button>`

then i am guessing the div to be

`<div id="English">English Content</div> etc`.

If this is the case then you can try this:

```
 $("#graybox button").click(function() {
     var div2show = $(this).text();
     $('#whitebox').find(div2show).show().siblings().hide();
 });
```